# Python File Download

Tags: python

I am having a problem and not sure if this is possible at all, so if someone could point me in the right direction.

I need to open a file from a webpage, open it in excel and save the file.

The problem I am running into the file name on the website has a file name ( not an active link ) and then it will have a "download " button that is not specific to the file I need to download. So instead of the download button being "file1todaysdate",  they are nothing that I could use from day to day.

Is there a way I could locate file name then grab the file from the download icon? then save in excel? If not sorry for wasting time.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are asking is how to search a web page for some text that is not a link, request that link, save the file.

[BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) is normally used for this.

However, [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/) is another library you can use to fetch the page and then grab the contents for later analysis.

Answer (score 2):

When you press Download, where the file actually coming from? Get that download link first. If it is hard to detect from the browser, use a tool like firebug to get the download link. Once you got it. You can use Python to dowload it using urllib.urlretrieve

```
filename, msg = urllib.urlretrieve('http://yourlinktodownload/file.xls')
```

The filename will point to the file which was downloaded. If it xls format, it should open in excell.

Answer (score 0):

Examine the `Content-Disposition` header of the response to discover what the server wants you to call the file.